# How to count input with automatic commas

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, input

How I can count two input if have automatical commas, and still show a comma on display?

HTML

```html
<input data-type="number" class="form-control number " name="meals_living_expression" id="meals_living_expression" required onwheel="this.blur()">
    
<input data-type="number" class="form-control number" name="other_expenses" id="other_expenses" required onwheel="this.blur()">

<input data-type="number" class="form-control total number" name="total_cost" id="total_cost" max="50" disabled required>
```

JS for comma

```js
$('input.number').keyup(function (event) {
    if (event.which >= 37 && event.which <= 40) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    var $this = $(this);
    var num = $this.val().replace(/,/gi, "");
    var num2 = num.split(/(?=(?:\d{3})+$)/).join(",");
   
    });
```

My counting

```
$(function () {
    $("#meals_living_expression, #other_expenses").keyup(function () {
        $("#total_cost").val(+$("#meals_living_expression").val() + +$("#other_expenses").val());
       
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this

```
onKeyup="$(this).val(rp(this.value,''))"
```

change the jquery:

```
  function rp(angka, prefix) {
  var number_string = angka.replace(/[^,\d]/g, '').toString(),
      split = number_string.split(','),
      sisa = split[0].length % 3,
      rupiah = split[0].substr(0, sisa),
      ribuan = split[0].substr(sisa).match(/\d{3}/gi);

  if (ribuan) {
    separator = sisa ? '.' : '';
    rupiah += separator + ribuan.join('.');
  }

  rupiah = split[1] != undefined ? rupiah + ',' + split[1] : rupiah;
  $("#total_cost").val(parseInt($("#meals_living_expression").val().replace('.', '')) + parseInt($("#other_expenses").val().replace('.', '')));
  return prefix == undefined ? rupiah : rupiah;
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/satria08/np172605/9/)